# Xcode - content offset in scroller view

Tags: scrollview

I have a bug I've been looking at for over two hours and still don't know why it happens. 
I have a registration form on a scroller view, which scrolls down if they keyboard is in the way of the textfield (function called at Editing Did Start).
Here's the code segment where the bug happens:

```
CGPoint scrollerOffset = scroller.contentOffset;
UITextField *currentTextField = sender;
CGPoint textFieldOrigin = currentTextField.frame.origin;


if (scrollerOffset.y < textFieldOrigin.y) {
    scrollerOffset.y = textFieldOrigin.y - currentTextField.frame.size.height;
    NSLog(@"Offset: %f",scrollerOffset.y);
    [scroller setContentOffset:scrollerOffset animated:YES];
}
```

Now here's where the fun starts.

If I have the simulator like this and click inside the Phone Nr field, NSLog shows 590.000 for scrollerOffset.y and the text field jumps all the way to the top of the scrollview, as it should, just as the image next to it shows.

[image: 1] [image: 2]

BUT if I have the simulator like this and click inside the Phone Nr field, NSLog shows 590.000 again but the scrollview doesn't jump up to show the text field...

[image: 3] [image: 3]

Edit: If I don't animate the scrolling, it works perfectly, only bugs out when it's animated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've found the solution after a day of thinking, so if anyone has the same problem, heres's the solution:

Solution from here: http://www.pressingquestion.com/1128098/Disable-Uiscrollview-Scrolling-When-Uitextfield-Becomes-First-Responder

Basically, iOS has an in-built scroller, which is also scrolling for you if the text field is off the screen (usually the center of the text field is off the screen, off the screen being out of view, if it's hidden by the keyboard, it's still considered to be on the screen). So I called my function, did the scrolling, then iOS did his scrolling and messed me up. So you need to disable iOS' in-built scrolling.